# WCF nettcpbinding in windows phone 8?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8, nettcpbinding

I have WCF Service with nettcpbinding endpoint , how can I consume this service in WP8?,

I don't want to use sockets because I don't want to change the implementation of my service, is there any way to consume the service using sockets?

Will nettcpbinding be supported in the next versions of WP8, if yes then when?

Comment: Do you intend to use the service over an Intranet? Not sure if it is possible to use NetTCP otherwise, but [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx) states "This binding is an appropriate Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) system-provided choice for communicating over an **Intranet**."

Comment: Hello josh am using nettcp for communicating over internet , its also works behind nat , i want to use nettcpbinding with service callback in windows phone 8 , is there any way to do this ? Calling the service using sockets ?

Answer (score 0):

I not using WCF (but that *.asmx), Its more simple type of services but this solution maybe work too for you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Helli lukas , asmx does not support nettcpbinding , its just support basichttpbinding , its not my case , thank you man

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it yourself.
It's not that hard, and the protocol stack is well-documented.
[See this article](http://const.me/articles/net-tcp/) for an overview.

WP7-8 already includes binary XML serialization used by nettcp, namely XmlDictionaryReader and XmlDictionaryWriter classes. So, you only need to implement the lower-level pieces of the protocol, i.e. the framing protocol, and SOAP envelopes.